# When given the subspace topology by $\Bbb{R}$, all sets in $\Bbb{Z}$ are open?

Tags: general-topology

Is this statement true?

My thinking is that if we consider $\Bbb{Z}$ with the subspace topology from $\Bbb{R}$. Then a set is open in $\Bbb{Z}$ if its of the form $\Bbb{Z}\cap A$, where $A$ is open in $\Bbb{R}$.

From here it seems any set, $B\subseteq\Bbb{Z}$ is open, since we can just look at each element of $B$ and find an open interval which contains that integer and that integer only. Then we take the union of these intervals to get our set A, so that $\Bbb{Z}\cap A=B$

Is my argument correct or have I missed something?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is entirely correct, yes. All subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ are open in the subspace topology (so this subspace has the so-called discrete topology).

Comment: Would the same apply to $\Bbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: @ConnorBishop No, as any open interval in the reals contains infinitely many rationals.